# Enviar/recibir datos a través de Raspberry Pi 3 con Python

Tags: python, socket, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

Estoy realizando mi Trabajo Fin de Grado sobre la conexión de una Raspberry Pi 3 y un microcontrolador Pycom.

Se trata de que el Pycom ejecute un temporizador que encienda cada cierto tiempo la RPi, ésta al encenderse, ejecutará de forma automática un programa (toma una foto y realiza una serie de cálculos con ella), una vez obtenga el resultado lo mandará al Pycom y este la apagará e iniciará de nuevo el temporizador.

Ya he conseguido que realice la foto y los cálculos, y que todo ello lo haga de forma automática al encenderse, sin embargo, no sé como hacer para que envíe dicha información al Pycom. (Estoy programando con Python!)

Había pensado, si fuera posible, que en el mismo script de Python, se envíe el resultado por Bluetooth (el resultado es un número entero), pero tampoco sé como se haría esto, ni si es una opción adecuada...

No me importa que se ejecute en segundo plano, o no se muestre por pantalla, de hecho, para la aplicación real del proyecto no habrá ninguna pantalla.. lo importante es que la Raspberry envíe un número al Pycom, y cuando éste lo haya recibido apague la raspberry (saque 0 por una salida que ira conectada a la RPi con un relé).

Cualquier contribución sería de gran ayuda!!!

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Maria, bienvenida a SOes. Aun cuando tu pregunta es valida, para los lineamientos de este sitio, es demasiado amplia. Te recomiendo varias cosas: lee el [tour] cuanto antes. Considera leer todo lo que puedas en el [help], en especial los articulos [ask] y [mcve]. Debes elegir una forma de hacerlo y proporcionar lo que llevas hecho para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Qué interfaz de comunicaciones tiene la Pycom? ¿Usa Wifi? Esa sería la opción más sencilla.